# Where are the paintings in each world?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

It's clear that without the paintings, you'll be unable to find some moons. However, these are fairly well hidden in each world. Where can each painting in each world be found?

Comment: @Maximillian That's why I said "painting**s**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Cascade Kingdom**: In a cave behind the waterfall
- **Bowser's Kingdom**: From the Main Courtyard Entrance flag, on the back wall of the building on your left
- **Seaside Kingdom**: in the bottom of the giant Bubblaine glass
- **Lake Kingdom**: In the bottom of the fishing Lakitu pond on the south of the map
- **Desert Kingdom**: South of the inverted pyramid, on a pillar in the sand near a Jaxi station
- **Metro Kingdom**: Behind the Odyssey, on a small ledge
- **Wooded Kingdom**: From the Iron Cage flag, on the back of an iron block on a platform to the north
- **Luncheon Kingdom**: On the back of the island with the Remote Island in the Lava flag
- **Mushroom Kingdom**: From the Odyssey, to the south amid some trees
- **Snow Kingdom**: near the northeast of the map, close to an island in the icy water, using a wooden block that needs to be moved as a staircase

Comment: Judging by the Prima Guide, I believe that the destinations of the paintings can vary depending on the order choices you make at the “forks in the road”. I haven’t experienced it myself because I followed their order exactly...

Comment: @Margaret I think you're right - I was playing last night, going through the paintings to stock up on Moons and the one for Wooded Kingdom did not take me to Luncheon if I'm remembering correctly. The locations are static, at least, just not the destinations.

Comment: @Margaret this goes with what I've seen on my own vs.  other comments here.

Comment: They are different. Just checked my snow kingdom and it takes me to wooded kingdom. At least the locations are static!